# Why can't I run `su`? (and how should I do?)

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo

Whenever I try to issue `su` I get this:

```
$ su  
Password:  
su: Sorry
```

Needless to say, I'm entering the correct admin password which does work with `sudo`. What I want is not having to enter `sudo` each time.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In MacOS X, the root user is disabled by default, therefore `su` will not work. As others have stated, it's best to use `sudo`.

If you **must** enable the root user, see Apple's technote: [Enabling and using the "root" user in Mac OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528).

Comment: `sudo su` still works, so it is not really disabled. It just has no password.

Comment: @FakeName This is the most hilarious backdoor! If you can run `sudo su`, what in the world is the point of disabling `su` then?

Comment: @KolobCanyon - The point isn't really to "disable `su`", it's to *prevent root login*. By disallowing login as `root`, you prevent a bunch of possible security issues. Not allowing someone who can `sudo` to `su` is kind of silly.  Basically, `su` just changes the current user-id, and executes a command (a shell, if not specified). If the user-id is already 0 (root), such as when executed with `sudo`, there's nothing for it to do, so it just executes the shell. You can get a similar effect by doing `sudo bash`.

Comment: @FakeName Still confused. What's the difference between logging in as root and running 'sudo su'? Isn't it effectively the same level?

Comment: @KolobCanyon - Nope. Basically, if you disable *login*, it means that if there is a vulnerability in the login process, a hacker cannot use it to get root directly. Basically, it moves the required root compromise from "login compromise" to "login comprimise for user account + privesc". It's basically done as a defence-in-depth thing.

Comment: To get root using terminal: sudo su

Comment: Here's what I don't get: I ran `sudo su -` and entered the current user's password, and got a root shell.  Then I tried `su otheruser -`, from my root shell, and got `su: Sorry`.  WTF, Apple?  I'm `root`, don't tell me "Sorry"!  Is this (terrible) behavior actually documented somewhere official?

Comment: @JamesB - try `su - otheruser`.  This is documented under `man su`

Answer (score 22):

You have two options. The first is to use `sudo -s` - this will give you superuser access, but you will still remain 'yourself' (so to speak), so things like `~` will still be your home directory. Alternatively, you can use `sudo su`, which gives you a shell as the actual root user of your Mac.

Comment: The Apple Way(tm) is to use `sudo` to run commands that require elevated privileges, not to switch to a root shell and work from that.

Comment: @Ian C. - No, that's actually the unix way. Apple just uses it because it is *nix based too.

Comment: @Fake Name: Apple goes through great pains to never talk or expose the root shell to users. You could say they take the `sudo` ethos to the extreme. But whatever: semantics. Don't use root shells in OS X.

Comment: @Ian C - Apple doesn't do much more than the \*nix designers do, Apple just doesn't talk about it much. In both cases, it's there, only with things like linux, they tell you how to use it easily. If that makes it more widely *used*, it doesn't indicate an underlying architecture difference.

Answer (score 7):

## Modern solution: `sudo -u`

To run as another use, use `sudo -u`.

For example, to run a [text-editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor) such as [*nano*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano):

```bash
sudo -u someuser nano
```

…and enter your Mac admin user password when prompted. At this juncture, it is your Mac admin user who is invoking `sudo`, not the `someuser` user so you do not enter the `someuser` password.

- `sudo` means to run something using superuser privileges.
- `-u` means “run a specified command as this specified user”.
- `someuser` should be replaced with your desired user name.

To simulate an initial login as a particular user, including running their startup scripts, use `-I`.

```bash
sudo -u someuser -i nano
```

This runs the `nano` app as the user `someuser` but only after having run the startup scripts for that user.

If we opt to not specify a command or app to run, we get an interactive shell running as that user.

```bash
sudo -u someuser -i
```

## Old-school: `sudo su someuser`

Another approach uses the `su` command in combination with the `sudo`. The `su` command means “switch user”.

```bash
sudo su someuser
```

Or, to include running the user's startup scripts, add the hyphen.

```bash
sudo su - someuser
```

## `root` user

The `root` user in Unix-related operating systems have absolute power to do anything.

Apple has chosen to disable the `root` account in macOS, to avoid security vulnerability exploits and to protect you from shooting yourself in the foot. Apple created the idea of the *Administrator* user accounts who have many powers, more powers than a *Standard* user account, but not absolute power like `root` has. See [this Apple Support note](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25796?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) for discussion.

If need be, you *can* enable the `root` user in macOS and then switch to that user. This is *strongly* discouraged. I would go down this path only as a desperate last resort.

---

For discussion of this within the context of the `postgres` user running the [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database system on macOS, see [this Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/221043/19079) on the sister site, [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do this as a "normal" user...

If there is another user account with admin rights you have to use this one

```
restricted user$ su
Password:(the root password here)
Sorry!

restricted user$ su - (an admin account here)
password:(the admin account password)
$ su - root
Password:(The root password here)
# -> You are root user now
```

Comment: This is because of a line in /etc/pam.d/su.  `account required pam_group.so ...` is telling the system to only allow su to root if you are switching from an account in the `admin` or `wheel` group.  You can comment-off this line if you really want to, but I wouldn't since it isn't really necessary for those (hopefully rare) occasions when you need to become root.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, if you need move files or use git using the CLI then, in that case, the best solution will be to use the `sudo -s` command. After that command, you don't have to keep entering the password again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and as @Nohillside suggested, there is no way to access root through the *su* command as a normal user just using *su*. As stated, adding the admin account to the *su* command is recognized. I was able to connect as root that way. It's not something I will do often. I just wanted to test it and the result was an immediate connection.

```
> admin-server:~ admin$ su
> Password:
> su: Sorry
> admin-server:~ admin$ su - admin
> Password:
> admin-server:~ admin$
```

Comment: interesting! i prefer `sudo su` since it also works on linux.

Answer (score -2):

Try the password `alpine`?! Legend has it that `alpine` was the root password on macOS for many years! You can get to root from an admin account shell with:

```
sudo su
```

I recommend then changing the password for root with:

```
passwd
```

After this I can just run `su` and type the actual root password. Handy for going root from a regular user account.